# Requirements management with equations and doc/docx

Tags: project-management

I am looking for a requirements management tool with the following features:

- support for equations
- export to doc/docx format (generation of requirements documents)
- requirements change tracking
- user defined requirements numbering
- user defined parameters for a requirement
- preferably free or open source

A few more details to the equations:

- Complex equations with integration, derivation, fractions, matrices, ...
- Directly editable in the tool (like with Latex equations or Microsoft Office equations)

Any suggestion is welcome.

**Edit1:** I want to manage a set of requirements during the project life cycle. Meaning writing user/system/test/non-functional requirements, modifying them as needed while keeping track of the changes. There are many tools that do exactly that, some with more functionality than others, but I didn't find any that was able to deal with my need of being able to add/edit equations and to easily export it to a Microsoft Word doc/docx.

**Edit2:** I found [CodeBeamer](http://www.intland.com/products/codebeamer), seems to do what I want. However, it is not free so I am still looking if there is a free alternative.

Comment: What do you want to manage? Do you have a user story to explain your context?

Comment: @Fractaliste I want to manage a set of requirements as they are created/evolve/change/disappear during a project life cycle. Also see the edit.

Comment: Export to Doc/Docx and preserving equations is a hard to furfil requirement because there are very few good implementations of the docx format. I expect you might find something that is dependent on the MS-Office interopt library. I'm interested to know.
I also do think exporting to docx is very bad idea (export to pdf. Always.) but I realise it is probably outside of your control.

Comment: @Oxinabox Sadly the export to docx is required (not my decision). The export of equations as image would be acceptable, but they must be editable in the tool.